# Highlighting duplicates within and across sheets in excel

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am trying to Highlight duplicates within and across sheets in excel. Each sheet is set up the same and I only need column C checked. I also want to ignore blank cells. I tried to google this, but couldn’t find what i was looking for.

I am familiar with Excel and i know how to input something into VBA, but that is the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: Look into conditional formatting

Comment: Thank you. I did, but I couldn't figure out how to run it within the whole workbook.

Comment: Maybe clarify in more detail what you're trying to do - and the structure of the file/sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Sub HiliteDupsAcrossSheets()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, c As Range, v
    Dim dict As Object
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'for example
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        'col C only
        For Each c In ws.Range("C1:C" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            v = c.Value
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                If dict.exists(v) Then
                    If Not dict(v) Is Nothing Then
                        dict(v).Interior.Color = vbRed 'color the first instance
                        Set dict(v) = Nothing          ' mark done
                    End If
                    c.Interior.Color = vbRed   'color cell `c`
                Else
                    Set dict(v) = c  'first time seeing this value: store location
                    c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'clear any previous coloring
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you :). That works. Data is inputted daily, will it automatically update to highlight new duplicates?

Comment: No - you will need to run it to refresh the coloring.  You'll also need to clear any coloring from the previous run in case those cells are no longer duplicates.

Comment: Added a line to clear hiliting from a previous run.