Excel VBA Highlight Cells Based on Same Groups from Different Column
I have a large data set in which Column A specifies a Group name and column D specifies a number that needs to be unique PER group.
I'd like to use VBA to highlight any Duplicate cells in Column D, for same Groups from Column A.
Ex:
In this case, cells for Group 1 containing "20" would be highlighted and cells for Group 2 containing "33" would be highlighted.



A
B
C
D




Group 1


20


Group 1


15


Group 1


12


Group 1


16


Group 1


2


Group 1


20


Group 2


1


Group 2


33


Group 2


18


Group 2


15


Group 2


4


Group 2


33




Any reason you're looking at VBA? Conditional formatting will work nicely.

Another idea is to use a formula to calculate the number of duplicates, e.g. =COUNTIFS($A:$A,"="&$A2,$D:$D,"="&$D2)

@BigBen I've found that with these large data sets, conditional formatting can make the sheet a bit sluggish. Also, I like that with VBA, as the data set changes I don't to worry about updating formatting. Out of curiosity, did you have a Conditional Formatting formula idea that I could try and see how the performance is?

Based on COUNTIFS for example, tho I understand the performance concerns. I don't quite follow the comment about data set changing. That's the whole point of conditional formatting; it updates as the data set changes.

@BigBen re: data set changing - I just meant that with VBA I wouldn't have to update the conditional formatting range.

@nok - Why not convert that data to a proper Table,, and apply the Conditional Formatting to the table? AFAIK when you add more rows to the table, the CF won't "break" as easily as a non-table.

@DmitryO. this seems to only highlight the cell if two cells of the same value are right next to each other.

Since you'd like to do this using VBA - what exactly is the blocker there for you?  Is there some specific part of the process which you're having a problem with?  You need to loop over the rows in the table and check for duplicates (you could use countifs from VBA, or a dictionary with a composite key of Avalue+Dvalue)  Similar previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68896698/478884

@TimWilliams thanks for the link. I'm having trouble applying this to my specific situation. I can modify the code for the Column that may have dups but making sure that the dups are only evaluated for each Group is my issue.

In that code the dictionary key is from column C - instead you make the key from ColAValue & "<>" & ColDValue, because you want to track unique combinations of those two values.

@nok  it calculates the number of the rows containing the same value within the  same group in the entire range, no matter where in the range the rows are.

Modifying my linked post:
Sub HiliteDups()
    Const HILITE_COLOR = vbRed
    Dim ws As Worksheet, k
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, data, r As Long
     
    'Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 'Windows
    Set dict = New Dictionary                        'Cross-platform
    '   (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary)
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:D" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Columns(4).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'clear flags
    data = rng.Value  'get data as array (for faster looping)
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)           'loop over range data
        k = data(r, 1) & "<>" & data(r, 4) 'composite key A+D
        If dict.Exists(k) Then
            If dict(k) > 0 Then 'need to color the first row for this key?
                rng.Cells(dict(k), 4).Interior.Color = HILITE_COLOR
                dict(k) = 0
            End If
            rng.Cells(r, 4).Interior.Color = HILITE_COLOR 'color this row
        Else
            dict.Add k, r 'remember this row in case there are duplicates later
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

EDIT - allow for use of cross-platform dictionary class from:
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary
And another alternative: using a Collection with keys
Sub HiliteDups()
    Const HILITE_COLOR = vbRed
    Dim ws As Worksheet, k As String, valA, valD
    Dim col As Collection, rng As Range, data, r As Long, v
     
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:D" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Columns(4).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'clear flags
    data = rng.Value  'get data as array (for faster looping)
    
    Set col = New Collection 'for tracking unique A+D combinations
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)           'loop over range data
        valA = data(r, 1)
        valD = data(r, 4)
        If Len(valA)>0 And Len(valD)>0 Then
            k = valA & "<>" & valD 'composite key A+D
            v = KeyValue(col, k)
            If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
                If v > 0 Then 'need to color the first row for this key?
                    rng.Cells(v, 4).Interior.Color = HILITE_COLOR
                    col.Remove k 'remove keyed value
                    col.Add 0, k 're-add as zero
                End If
                rng.Cells(r, 4).Interior.Color = HILITE_COLOR 'color this row
            Else
                col.Add Item:=r, Key:=k 'remember this row and key in case there are duplicates later
            End If  'key was found?
        End If      'values in A and D?
    Next r
End Sub

'Retrieve value for key `k` from collection `col`
'  Returns Empty if there's no such key
Function KeyValue(col As Collection, k As String)
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no match for `k`
    KeyValue = col.Item(k)
End Function


Thanks so much for modifying this. I'm getting an ActiveX error, most likely because I'm using Excel for Mac. Is there an alternative?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24422819/478884 for example - a Mac-compatible Dictionary class.  Or alternatively - https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary

Updated above to use the class from Tim Hall - https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary

Thanks for both of these! The Collection seems to be quite a bit faster and is great because it doesn't require the Dictionary.

Yes it looks like the key-based access using a Collection is a little bit faster than the Dictionary from the Scripting library.

I just noticed that this is highlighting empty Column D cells (as dups), is there a simple way around that? it looks like your code IS checking for empty cells and ignoring them.

You can add a check to make sure there's something in Col D:  If Len(data(r, 4)) > 0 Then (or check both A and D values)

See my edits above in the Collection-based code example

Works great, thanks again!
